# Create read-only column in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, readonly

How to create read-only column in SharePoint2010 use SP Designer or from SP Portal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen nothing the UI or the Designer to make a read only field in a list.  There are a couple of ways to do this through code.

You can create the field in the list definition in a SharePoint project and set the Read Only value to true.  [Article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/manish_ahuja/archive/2009/11/03/sharepoint-readonly-site-column.aspx) that shows how this works.

You can also set it in code in a Feature Activated method for example.

```
    SPField f = new SPField(TaskList.Fields, "MyReadOnlyField");
    f.ReadOnlyField = true;
    f.Update();
```